# I have a code here, I want to find the total number of females and males in a certain csv file.

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('admission_data.csv')
df.head()
female = 0
male = 0
for row in df:
    if df['gender']).any()=='female':
       female = female+1             
    else:
       male = male+1
```

print (female)
   print male

The CSV file has 5 columns[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juN4I.png)

I want to find the total number of females, males and number of them admitted, number of females admitted, males admitted 
Thank you. This is the code I have tried and some more iterations of the above code but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Please put your image into your question, not as a link.

Comment: What specifically is going wrong? What's your desired output and how does it differ from the actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the below csv file:

```
student_id,gender,major,admitted
35377,female,chemistry,False
56105,male,physics,True
31441,female,chemistry,False
51765,male,physics,True
31442,female,chemistry,True
```

Reading the csv file into dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('D:/path/test1.csv', sep=',')
df[df['admitted']==True].groupby(['gender','admitted']).size().reset_index(name='count')

df
    gender  admitted    count
0   female  True    1
1   male    True    2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

1. Your `if` logic is wrong.
2. No need for a loop at all.

```
print(df['gender'].tolist().count('female'))
print(df['gender'].tolist().count('male'))
```

Alternatively you can use `value_counts` as @Wen suggested:

```
print(df['gender'].value_counts()['male'])
print(df['gender'].value_counts()['female'])
```

Rule of thumb: 99% of the times there is no need to use explicit loops when working with pandas. If you find yourself using one then there is most probably a better (and faster) way.

Comment: I am getting `KeyError: 'Level female must be same as name (None)'` when I try this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Phew! I thought I was going crazy

Answer (score 3):

You just need `value_counts`

```
df['gender'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use these brother,

```
// This line creates create a data frame which only have gender as male
count_male=df[df['Gender']=="male"]
// 2nd line you are basically counting how many values are there in gender column
count_male['Gender'].size
```

(or)

```
count_male=df['Gender']=="male"]
count_male.sum()
```

Answer (score -2):

Take the values in the column `gender`, store in a list, and count the occurrences:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('admission_data.csv')

print(list(df['gender']).count('female'))
print(list(df['gender']).count('male'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!!

Comment: ALso can someone tell me how to find number of female that are admitted and number of male that are admitted.